# Iterating through a block of text without writing it in a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm accepting a set of lines by input() function in a loop untill it encounters EndofInput and storing it in a text string. Now this input is a block of text . How do I work on this text data without writing this to a file ? I need to do some operations based on this input data . How do I iterate?

> Courses
>   POT~Potions~1~2011-2012~Severus Snape
>   DADA~Defence Against the Dark ARTS~1~2011-2012~Gilderoy Lockhart
>   Students
>   RAV4309~Angelina Johnson
>   HUF7201~Gwenog Jones
>   GRF9110~Parvati Patil
>   RAV4308~Olive Hornby
>   Grades
>   POT~1~2011-2012~RAV4308~C
>   POT~1~2011-2012~RAV4309~B
>   POT~1~2011-2012~GRF9110~A
>   EndOfInput

```
lines = []
line="String"
while line != "EndOfInput":
        line = input();
        lines.append(line)


text = '\n'.join(lines)
print(text)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are referring to where you read the input using `input()`?

Comment: Your question suggests that you know how to iterate through it *with* writing it to a file; can't you just use that and comment-out the write?

Comment: @ScottHunter I have not written it to a file as you can see . Writing to file is not allowed . Instead i'm printing it on python interpreter just after taking the input

Comment: You have a list of lines, why not iterate over it instead of converting it to a string? You can do it either way, but if you already have a list then you might as  well use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting all of the input into a single string variable, but want to work on each line individually after you've read all the input, take a look at the [.split method on strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)

For example, if your complete string is stored in the variable `input`, you could do something like

```
for line in input.split("\n"):
 #do something with that line
```

Comment: Yeah, OP edited that in moments after I'd submitted this comment. (Just use `lines` instead of `input.split("\n")`)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list of lines. Simply iterate over the list without converting it to a string.

```
while line != "EndOfInput":
    line = input();
    lines.append(line)

# you now have a list of lines, which you can easily iterate over
for line in lines:
    print("line:", line)
```

Comment: that  helped ..Thanks !! @bryan oakley

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like:

```
inputText = input()
doStuff = True
for l in inputText.split("\n"):
    if l.find('EndOfInput') > -1:
        doStuff = False
    if doStuff:
        #do what you want with the line
```

Comment: This won't quite work because the  code in the question doesn't add "EndOfInput" to `inputText`.

Comment: In the list of strings @k_roy provided "EndOfInput" is already the last line. Furthermore, the way the question is worded the goal is to iterate over the lines until you encounter the line "EndOfInput".

Comment: I guess we have different interpretations of the question. To me it looks like the OP already has the code to read the data in one line at a time, and now needs to iterate over the data after all of the input is done. The code in the question shows an array being filled within all input _except_ when it is `EndOfInput`.